# ASP.NET MVC EF adding tags and to a link table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have viewmodel that contains all the data. I need to store specific data in the right table.

My Tables:

1. [Company] Id, Name ...etc
2. [Tags] Id, Title
3. [CompanyTags] (link between Tag and Company) Id, TagId(FK), CompanyId(FK)

   ```
   public class CompanyTags
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int CompanyAccountId { get; set; }
      public virtual CompanyAccount CompanyAccount { get; set; }        
      public int TagsId { get; set; }
      public virtual Tags Tags { get; set; }
   }
   ```

In the controller this is what I have:

```
 var companyAccount = new CompanyAccount
 {
     Name = viewModel.Name,            
 };

 foreach (var t in viewModel.Tags)
 {
      var tag = new Tags()
      {
          Title = t
      };                       
      context.Tags.Add(tag);
```

It fails in the below code. The values are empty and an exception is executed:

Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Models.CompanyTags_Tags' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Do I need to add the CompanyAccountId and TagsId to CompanyTags table? or somehow EF can add it by default?

```
      var companyTag = new CompanyTags()
      {
         CompanyAccountId = companyAccount.Id,
         TagsId = tag.Id
      };
      context.CompanyTags.Add(companyTag);

  }
   context.CompanyAccount.Add(companyAccount);
   context.SaveChanges();
```

I think my logic is incorrect, how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you configuring EF? Are you using Database First, Code First?

Comment: @Jasen using code first

Comment: Unless you need additional fields on the Company-Tag relation you don't need to explicitly define a `CompanyTags` entity.

Comment: So If I remove the code that adds the compnayTag. Then how do I add CompanyAccountId and TagsId to CompanyTags table? if you can please provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to define the relation entity. You'll have three tables but only two entities. The relation is handled with navigation properties and Fluent API configuration.

Navigation properties Tags and Companies

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Tags = new List<Tags>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    public Tags()
    {
        this.Companies = new List<Company>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Many-to-Many relation configured with Fluent API in your DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Tags)
        .WithMany(t => t.Companies)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("Companyd");
            m.MapRightKey("AgentId");
            m.ToTable("CompanyTags");
        }
}
```

Your usage code depends on whether you are creating new rows. Here's a new Company and new Tags.

```
// new Company
var company = new Company() { Name = "FooBar Inc" };

// new Tags
// for loop if you wish
company.Add(new Tag { Title = "tag1" });
company.Add(new Tag { Title = "tag2" });

context.Companies.Add(company);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This should create a new Company, new Tags, and the relation rows.

Comment: Thanks Jasen for your example. I am confused about the existing tag code. How do I get the tagid? in the loop I add the tag into the table context.Tags.Add(tag) and only on SaveChanges() it gets stored so how does this work? var tag = context.Tags.Single(t => t.Id == tagId);company.Tags.Add(tag); please elaborate how it works and how I get the tagid? I also noticed you are not using "virual" keyword any reason why? thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add virtual. For the tagId, that's just an example when you do know the Id. I changed the example to use the tag Title.

Comment: I still dont get it. How can you compare title with the Tags tbl title since savechanges() not been executed and the Tags table has no data stored yet. Sorry I am lost are you able to update your code to show me how would you add Tags and CompanyTags in the foreach loop I have. thanks for your help!

Comment: See edit. There's more than one way to do this. You can either save tags and companies first then set the relation to existing rows. Or attempt to create everything at once.

Comment: Hi Jasen, I have used your code but have some confusing on how to do update mapping, can you please see ticket I created and if you can point me to the right place much appreciated.. thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092567/mvc4-save-data-using-many-to-many-relationship